# Connect VS2010 to a online SQL Server database through proxy

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, proxy

I can connect through my Visual Studio to my online SQL Server database when I work from home.
But I am unable to connect to the online SQL Server database from my office as we have a proxy.
Can you suggest a solution please...

Answer (score 0):

You can change the proxy settings of Visual Studio itself using it's devenv.exe.config file.

I have shown an example of doing it here:
http://gurustop.net/blog/2010/08/10/visual-studio-2010-extension-manager-online-gallery-behind-internet-proxy/

You can add `<defaultProxy>` under the `<system.net>` tag with the settings applicable to your case.

Comment: i have tried this before but the problem is still the same. thanx for the response

Comment: By "Connect" here, do you mean going to Server Explorer and adding a new connection? Are you able to ping the server from your office?

Comment: By connect i mean... when running the website from my visual studio, i cannot retrieve data from the online database, thus cannot perform operations like login and retrieval of data.

i am unable to ping the online database... "request timed out" "100% loss"

Comment: This is way different then, not Visual Studio at all. The changes will be needed in web.config or IIS/IISExpress. Plus, if you can't ping the serer, no proxy will save you. Looks like an issue related to the office network firewall or so, assuming the server itself is not at home but at a 3rd location remote to both home and office.

Comment: i used an app called sockscap control. can access the online db through the sql management studio, but not vs2010

Comment: Try changing the identity of your application pool to your username.